# How to input MS Access query into asp.net drop down button

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, drop-down-menu

I am making a drop down list in asp.net using the query in my MS Access but I don't know what to do. My list should be the name of the query and, when I click on the list, the inputs in my query should show up.

Also, how to make a graph using the inputs on my query?

```
</div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="24px" Width="268px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [602502]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

602502 is one of my queries. I try to input it in `sqldatasource` but my doings is unsuccessful.

My connection string is good; when I test it, connection are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's looking for you to set the columns from which the text and the values of the dropdown options are set.  For example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="24px" Width="268px" DataTextField="name-of-column" DataValueColumn="name-of-column">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

`DataTextField` is what is shown to the user for each option when they open the dropdown.  `DataValueField` is what is returned when you refer to `DropDownList1.SelectValue` in your code.

Also, you might want to consider modifying your query to select only the columns you need for those fields.  I don't how many columns that table has, but you might be pulling back a lot of extra data just to fill two properties in the dropdown.

Comment: i have 10 column in my table, i edit my query to show only 3 columns.. i need to show 41 items in my drop down list. from 602502 to 606502 . </asp:DropDownList> i will input here all my queries ?

Comment: No, you can leave your query where it is.  Just set the values for the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` attributes on the dropdowns with names of columns returned by the query.  `DataTextField` is what the users will see.  `DataValueField` is what is put in the `value` attribute of the option elements of the dropdown.